# Creating wiki links reading form xml in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read all the links in the  tag and then trying to create wiki links out of it...basically I want to read each link from the xml file and then create wiki links with the last word(please see below on what I mean by lastword) of the link...for somereason am running into following error,what I am missing,please suggest

```
http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/CIT (last word is CIT)
http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/1.2_Archive(last word is 1.2_Archive)
```

INPUT XML:-

```
<returnLink>
    http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/CIT
    http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/1.2_Archive
</returnLink>
```

PYTHON code

```
 def getReturnLink(xml):
"""Collects the link to return to the PL home page from the config file."""
if xml.find('<returnLink>') == -1:
    return None
else:
    linkStart=xml.find('<returnLink>')
    linkEnd=xml.find('</returnLink>')
    link=xml[linkStart+12:linkEnd].strip()
    link = link.split('\n')
    #if link.find('.com') == -1:
        #return None
    for line in link:
        line = line.strip()
        print "LINE"
        print line
        lastword = line.rfind('/') + 1
        line = '['+link+' lastword]<br>'
        linklis.append(line)
    return linklis
```

OUTPUT:-

```
   line = '['+link+' lastword]<br>'
 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
CIT  (this will point to http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/CIT
1.2_Archive (this will point to http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/1.2_Archive 1.2_Archive)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intead of parsing XML by hand, use a library like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
>>> s = """<returnLink>
...     http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/CIT
...     http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/1.2_Archive
... </returnLink>"""
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml_tree = etree.fromstring(s)
>>> links = xml_tree.text.split()
>>> for i in links:
...    print '['+i+']'+i[i.rfind('/')+1:]
...
[http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/CIT]CIT
[http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/1.2_Archive]1.2_Archive
```

I'm not sure what you mean by wikilinks, but the above should give you an idea on how to parse the string.

Comment: @khalid -  am getting the following error and am using python 2.7 on windows7,what am I missing?   from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml

Comment: You are missing lxml. Download a windows installer for it [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: @Khalid - Thanks,also output should be like below,how should I edit the above code to achieve this    [hhttp://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/CIT CIT]
[hhttp://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/1.2_Archive 1.2_Archive]

Comment: Are you really telling me you can't figure that out by yourself? @user1795998

Comment: Thanks Khalid,I figured that out

Comment: there is no need to install 3rd party xml module in this case. `urlparse` can help to parse urls. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13330756/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Python standard library has xml parser. You can also support multiple `<returnLink>` elements and Unicode words in an url:

```
import posixpath
import urllib
import urlparse
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

def get_word(url):
    basename = posixpath.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(url).path)
    return urllib.unquote(basename).decode("utf-8")

urls = (url.strip()
        for links in etree.parse(input_filename_or_file).iter('returnLink')
        for url in links.text.splitlines())
wikilinks = [u"[{} {}]".format(url, get_word(url))
             for url in urls if url]
print(wikilinks)
```

Note: work with Unicode internally. Convert the text to bytes only to communicate with outside world e.g., when writing to a file.

[Example](http://ideone.com/jODrrr)

```
[http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/CIT#some-fragment CIT]
[http://wiki.build.com/ca_builds/Unicode%20%28%E2%99%A5%29 Unicode (♥)]
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't think to go this way. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some difficulty understanding you question, but it seems like you just want to return the string after the last '/' character in the link? You can do this with reverse find.

```
return link[link.rfind('/') + 1:]
```

Comment: sorry about not being clear...getting string after the last '/' character is part of the final goal..my final goal is to create wikilinks, ideally ['+link+' lastword] should create a link with "lastword" as the link name...i updated the code with the latest I have based on your suggestion